# How to install ubuntu properly?

Tags: boot

I am using laptop. My laptop's configuration: 1000 GB hard drive, 4 GB ram, 6th generation core i 5, Intel(R) HD Graphics 520. I have added 8 GB ram and 128 GB SSD.

I install ubuntu on my SSD card (m2, 128 GB). I use rufus to boot a pen drive. My partition system is MBR (both ssd and hdd).

After installing ubuntu, when I turn off( not reboot or restart) my laptop and again start it, after giving log in password my laptop's screen are totally blank (purple screen). and if some how I manage to bring back the screen, my laptop automatically filling the space. After some time when it completely fill up space I cannot open any application even I cannot turn of my pc.

I also install after converting from MBR to GPT and still facing same problem.

Ubuntu is my most favorite OS. But I cannot use it. I want to use is and want shift ubuntu permanently. Please help me. what should I do?

[image]

Comment: *if some how I manage to bring back the screen* -- How did you do that? *After some time when it completely fill up space* -- How much space do you have in your root partition? Ubuntu should not automatically fill up space unless you install programs. Also, which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I put down my screen and again put it up. then the screen come back. and there are no space in root partition left. I do not install anything  believe me it automatically fill up the space. I used 20.04 lts.

Comment: Just a wild thought: Closing the laptop suspends to disk (hibernation) and needs a lot of swap for that, yet swap is configured as a swap file in the root partition? Please add to your question the output of `swapon` and of `df -Tx tmpfs`.

Comment: There are a lot of things missing. 1.Which partition (of which disk i.e. hdd or ssd) you used to install ubuntu on? 2.What procedure did you follow to install ubuntu? 3.Are you saying the problem appeared when your system rebooted just for the first time after installing ubuntu? Edit your question and add this information first because ubuntu community can't answer your questions based on speculations. You need to provide more details regarding your issue.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht please check. thanks for the correction.

Comment: Ok, so you used rufus to create a bootable pen-drive and then installed Ubuntu using it. Actually I wanted to know the steps you performed during that installation process. So if and when your system boot up and you get an opportunity can you provide the result of `df -h | grep ^/dev` and post it in your question. It might help in solving the "full space" issue.